# Keyboard gets disabled automatically now and then

Tags: keyboard

I am running ubuntu 20.04 and sometime after I have logged in
[the screen shows this crosse circle and my keyboard stops working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzaVI.png) After a while It starts working again and again it stops working.

First I thought its a hardware problem and I cleaned my laptop a few times but nothing positive happened. I believe ths cross is shown because the OS somehow is running some unknown command. This is very similar to touchpad getting disabled symbol. I did not find any options in dconf editor.